# Creation of Recurrence Rules and Writing Unit Tests

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to create recurrence rules and write unit tests for those recurrence rules correct or not. I have a calendar in my database. If recurrence rule does not exist in the database. I need to add those rules into calendar in a database.
Anyone can help me how to create recurrence rules of our own and How to write unit test for that rule?

Comment: are these iCalendar RRULEs?

Comment: Yes, icalendar RRules

Answer (score 0):

I've found the easiest way to create RRULEs is to use Google Calendar.

Create a new calendar.

Create some recurring events

Export the calendar to see the RRULEs